# Maui build and publication issues

Tags: maui, visual-studio-mac-2022

I have a MAUI project that references 3 .dll's that are built with netstandard2.1. I am working on a Mac with Ventura MacOS and Visual Studio 2022 17.4.2. I am having a problem building the .ipa for the iOS platform. I can compile all of the elements of the project but when I run the command

`"dotnet publish -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -r:ios-arm64 --no-self-contained"`

I get 3 errors all related to the .dll project files not referencing .net6.0-ios.

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5):
> error NETSDK1005: Assets file
> '/Users/davidrutter/Projects/RadixIQDealerPortal/aspnet-core/src/RadixDealerPortal.HttpApi.Client/obj/project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-ios'.

I've tried several things and searched all over trying to find a solution but without success. If anyone has an idea how to resolve this I would be truly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the framework net6.0, net6.0-ios should not make a difference here as you are using --no-self-contained.
Leaving the options for net6.0-ios out should work too, as you already have the runtime defined.

TLDR;

remove -f:net6.0-ios

Comment: The only way the publish will work by removing -f:net6.0-ios is if I make net6.0-ios the only framework in the <TargetFrameworks> tag. I did that, but now when I run the publish command I get the following error: error : Empty ResolveFrameworkReference.RuntimePackPath while trying to read runtime components manifest. ResolvedFrameworkReference available: { Microsoft.NETCore.App, RuntimePackPath:  }

Comment: Could you try a more basic publishing
`dotnet publish -f net6.0-ios -c Release` or even `dotnet publish -c Release`

Comment: Oh you will need /p:ArchiveOnBuild too.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0